# Creating a class with all of my functions in java

Tags: java

How can I create a class with all my functions in java?
when I create functions (methods) in a class, I can't seem to use them in other class.
 I would like to create a single class for all the impotent  functions and call them from there

```
public class all_function(){

public int func1(...)
public int func2(...)
.
.
.
   }
```

and than for all other classes, using those functions

```
public class main_app
 function.func1(...)
```

when trying to do so I get an error indicating that the function is not declared etc.
thanks

Comment: declare your methods as `static` and you can access them with `all_function.func1(...)`, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Quincunx's answer in the comments is correct, but writing whole programs like this violates all sorts of OO principles, and it's not a good idea for readability, maintainability, etc. You probably want to go back and read some basic Java tutorials.

For example, to use a method outside of the class that declares it, you need to create an instance of that object:

```
public class Foo {
   public void doSomething() {
       System.out.println("I did something!");
   }
}

public class Bar {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Foo foo = new Foo();
       foo.doSomething();
   }
}
```

If you have a method that's not specific to the class that declares it (i.e., a utility class), though, then by all means declare it `static`:

```
public class Foo {
   public static void doSomething() {
       System.out.println("I did something!");
   }
}

public class Bar {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Foo.doSomething();
   }
}
```